# How to show Instagram user login page on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, instagram

Any one have any idea about how can I display the Instagram user login page into my iPhone app? I want to display users’ Instagram images after successful login only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got some sample code..

For iPad :

https://github.com/jaydee3/instagram4iPad

For iPhone :

https://github.com/hsandhu/HSInstagram/tree/master/HSInstagramSample/HSInstagramSample

Answer (score 2):

To do this I recommend taking a look at the *'Instagram API'* which will allows developers to make use of users *Instagram* photos and other details. You can check out the API developer's page here...

http://instagram.com/developer/